# Why can't I (101 rep) answer a protected question?

Tags: support, protected-questions

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/155509/is-there-a-secular-non-vulgar-alternative-to-for-heavens-sake) is protected: "To answer it, you must have earned at least 10 reputation on this site." I have 101 reputation, so why can I not post an answer?

Comment: How apposite! Given that question asks for "non-offensive expressions of exasperation", I bet a few more occurred to you when you discovered you weren't even able to post whatever you originally had in mind!

Comment: Yes, I believe I actually said "fiddlesticks!" out loud.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because you haven't earned over 10 rep **on this site**. You have been given the site association bonus, but that is not counted.

Comment: Aha, thanks. Having rep ain't enough -- ya gots to *earn* it! :)

Comment: That's confusing. So rep is stratified on a site between what you've earned there vs what got you your first hundred points? That seems like a difficult thing to compute.

Comment: @Mitch it's actually very simple: if you got the association bonus, your first 100 reps are ignored for this calculation.

Comment: @Matt So many hidden business rules!

Comment: Yes, it does seem a bit arbitrary. I wonder if this distinction is made in other parts of the site? I'm not sure that the same rules applies to other SE sites.

Comment: @BennettMcElwee It does. It's the same rule everywhere.

Comment: For example [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user), [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user) and [RPGs](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user).

Comment: The wording describing the question protection is misleading and/or incorrect. It says "posting an answer requires 10 reputation on this site." Two issues: 1) it doesn't mention that unearned rep (e.g., association bonus) is not counted and 2) it says "on this *site*," it should say "on this *question*." Right? Is there a way to file a bug report about this?

Comment: Site is correct. If you have earned at least an up vote on an answer to a different question, or at least one up vote on one or more other questions, then you can answer protected questions. It is just the association bonus that does not count in this calculation.

Comment: It should be changed then, the trust itself indicates that you are a good user and won't spam.